# Final accuracy for double vs single precision neural nets

Tags: deep-learning

I wonder if anyone had experience with training deep neural nets on, say, CIFAR10 or ILSVRC-2012 datasets and comparing the final results for single and double precision computations?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, but this is less of an answer and more of just information and a though experiment. I think this question will be hard to test just because using 64 bit will require CPU instead of the GPU and will increase runtime considerably.

First a paper on the subject from Vincent Vanhoucke at Google: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/37631.pdf. This paper is focused on optimizing deep networks on cpus and a huge area of optimization is using 'fixed-point SIMD' instructions which as explained in the next link equates to 8 bit precision (unless I'm mistaken). An explanation of this paper can be found at http://petewarden.com/2015/05/23/why-are-eight-bits-enough-for-deep-neural-networks/.

In my own experience, I've used 16 bit precision for my inputs instead of 32 bit for Deep Q-Learning and I've noticed no difference in performance. 
I'm not an expert in low level computing but what are the extra digits really helping with? The point of training is to maximize the probability the network will assign the correct class with a large margin (ie softmax output of 95%+). A +- difference of 0.0001 won't change the predicted class.